# como agregar fila al datagridview con sql sin borrar las filas anteriores?

Tags: c#

**Tengo este codigo es la consulta sql server **

```
 SqlCommand query_consultacitas;
                    query_consultacitas = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, PiezaSellar, SerieNueva, Checklist FROM Citas WHERE ID = " + idunidad + " AND IDusuario = " + idusuario + " AND IDubicacion = " + idubicacion + " AND IDplanta = "
                        + idplanta + "", cn);

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query_consultacitas);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    string[] row = { dt.ToString() };
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    gridview.Rows.Add(row);
```

**El detalle es que me agrega registros pero en la siguiente consulta me borra lo que tengo y coloca los nuevos valores, quisiera saber como puedo hacerle para que los vaya agregando al datagridview**

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo haria lo siguiente:

Inicializar la tabla con sus encabezados

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Aqui pon el tipo de dato que sean tus columnas
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("PiezaSellar", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("SerieNueva", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("SerieNueva", typeof(string)); 
dt.Columns.Add("Checklist", typeof(string));

//Aqui llamas la funcion de busqueda
AgregarFilas(dt);
AgregarFilas(dt);
AgregarFilas(dt);
```

y luego crear una función de busqueda

```
    public static void AgregarFilas(DataTable dt)
            {
    
                string sql = @"SELECT ID, PiezaSellar, SerieNueva, Checklist FROM Citas";
    
                var conn = new SqlConnection(stringConnection);
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
    
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                            dr["PiezaSellar"] = Convert.ToString(reader["PiezaSellar"]);
//Aqui pones todas las columnas
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda , ya lo intente asi como lo comentas pero tengo una duda al respecto en esta parte  dt.Rows.Add(dr2); aqui falta asignarselo al datagridview? o ahi ya deberia de mostrar en la tabla

Comment: Al momento de crear el datatable se lo asignas a DGV dataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda